# iOS data driven programmatically setting up views and actions ? Looking for advices

Tags: ios, xml, json, view

New to iOS, I have to make an app that will show photos and videos.
Could be simple, but there's a little bonus.
The app will have to download configuration based on user. ( xml or json )
After downloading this configuration, it will have to download the elements to be shown.

The app will have to show , based on configuration file, views with buttons.
Each button can be used to show another view with buttons or a photo album, or a video, or a pdf.

I don't know where to start.
I tried to search on google but english not being my mother tongue, I think I don't have the right words to search on.

So any advice on how to structure that and how to make it possible ( nothing is impossible ).

I'm not asking for code, but for guidelines.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English isn't my mother tongue, but most valuable information in English. I would suggest to find informations in books, they are usually with downloadable examples. This can be useful for you.

Also you can try "ios recipes" in google.

Finally, my version of guideline:

1. Download configuration in applicationDidFinishLoad:withOptions:
2. Develop classes with view controllers + xib files, for each term(video, photoAlbum, etc.)
3. NavigationController or TabBarController to navigate between viewControllers. (There are too much examples with it. I like TabBarController, and "Each button can be used to show another view with buttons or a photo album, or a video, or a pdf." - this is too easy with tabBarController, tabs instead of buttons).

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll search on that and books are about to be ordered ;)